# HTML5 Canvas - Redrawing a grid every frame decreases the frame rate

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm redrawing a grid every frame in HTML5 Canvas which does so inside a loop. This causes the frame rate to drop every 20 seconds or so and continues to drop.

The code for the grid is specifically at line 179: https://jsfiddle.net/9v8tr9Lm/ (which is also below). Removing these two loops do prevent the frame rate from dropping. This issue makes me wonder how in earth would I draw an overworld map, as if I have an array of values, I would need to loop through them too just like I would with the grid?

Any ideas how I can keep the grid while not allowing the frame rate to drop?

The JavaScript for the grid:

```
for (i$ = 0.5; i$ < 641; i$ += 32) {
  x = i$;
  $g.context.moveTo(x, 0);
  $g.context.lineTo(x, 640);
}
for (i$ = 0.5; i$ < 641; i$ += 32) {
  y = i$;
  $g.context.moveTo(0, y);
  $g.context.lineTo(640, y);
}
$g.context.strokeStyle = '#ddd';
$g.context.stroke();
```

Comment: Have a look at `Window.requestAnimationFrame()` utility. All such DOM updates should be done asynchronously through it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: I am using that. You can see my use of that at the bottom of the code in the jsfiddle. It calls the main function (redundant) which calls the render function which then renders the current screen and that's where the grid logic is.

Comment: $g.context.beginPath();

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/9v8tr9Lm/1/

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what was happening without beginPath? Would it be that despite the canvas being cleared, the previous paths are still in memory so when I then redraw the grid, it is redrawing all the previous paths too?

Comment: It's explained breefly in the dup. link, but clearRect doesn't clear any path info, only the pixels, so the next time you add path data it will accumulate with the old and eventually not be able to keep up. beginPath clears the path data.